# this reference refers to the instance itself Albahari casting

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{

    public class Panda
    {
        public Panda Mate;
        public void Marry(Panda partner)
        {
            Mate = partner;
            partner.Mate = this;
        }
    }


    class Program
        {

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                Panda female= new Panda { };
                Panda male= new Panda { };

                male.Marry(female);
              //  female.Marry(male);
                Console.WriteLine(male.Mate.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(female.Mate.ToString());

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code is from Albahari with my adding. How can I output related partners name to string? I wanna output male partner name and male partner name according to class relations. I need to return class instance name instead of returning name of its property.  Or name property should be automatically names as class instance.

```
I try 
            var name = nameof(female.Mate);
            Console.WriteLine(name);
            Console.ReadLine();
        } but this outputs "Mate"
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. You want to print out the names of the two variables as strings? ("male" and "female") Why don't you add a new string property to the Panda class with the "Name" of the Panda instance?

Comment: It's important that you understand that an object doesn't "know" which variable might refer to it (there could be 0 such variables, or multiple ones)... and the `nameof` operator just uses a compile-time constant. If you want an object to have a particular name, you need to add that as part of the state of the object

Comment: Daisy, thanks! It is very important. Steve, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Panda
{
    public string name;
    public Panda Mate;
    public void Marry(Panda partner)
    {
        Mate = partner;
        partner.Mate = this;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.name + " = " + Mate.name;
    }
}


class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Panda female = new Panda { };
        Panda male = new Panda { };

        female.name = "Lilly";
        male.name = "Shadow";

        male.Marry(female);
        //  female.Marry(male);
        Console.WriteLine(male.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(female.ToString());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

---

UPDATED

Please try this code

```
public class Panda
{
    public string name;
    public Panda Mate;
    public void Marry(Panda partner)
    {
        Mate = partner;
        partner.Mate = this;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.name + " = " + Mate.name;
    }
}


class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Panda female = new Panda { };
        Panda male = new Panda { };

        female.name = nameof(female);
        male.name = nameof(male);

        male.Marry(female);

        Console.WriteLine(male.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(female.ToString());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is really how I wanted  except I do not need property"Name" but I need  to return class instance name instead of returning name of its property. It should return male+female or female+male. Or name property should be automatically names as class instance.

Comment: var name = nameof(female.Mate);
            Console.WriteLine(name);
            Console.ReadLine();
        } But it outputs female.Mate

Comment: I have updated my answer, so it will give the variable name in the output, but i am using the name property to get the variable name

Comment: Perfecto Uno! Gracias!